# Make outside elements invisible, html css

Tags: html, css

I have the following html structure:

```html
<body>
    <div class="white">
        <table class="circleDataBack">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="circle">A</div>
                    <div class="circle">B</div>
                    <div class="circle marked">C</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

And i should make only the elements who have the class

```
marked
```

and make invisible all the outside the elements.
And the elements who have the class `marked` should save their positions and stay visible

Comment: If I understood you, you can use the `:not()` selector - `.circle:not(.marked){ visibility: hidden }`

Comment: Thanks for everyone. Solved the solution with Jquery: `function showOnlyDots() {
                $('*').not('td > div.circle.marked').addClass('invis');
                $('img').css("display", "none");
                $('div.circle').css("border", "none");
            }`

Answer (score 4):

Use visibility.

```css
.circle{
  visibility: hidden;
}
.circle.marked{
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="white">
        <table class="circleDataBack">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="circle">A</div>
                    <div class="circle">B</div>
                    <div class="circle marked">C</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: 1 second before me... :D

Comment: @Tom thanks for your answer. I tried the code, but it made invisible only table data. However, i havle another blocks that has no relationship to the tds. i tried with Jquery like selecting all elements exceptiong marked and make it invisible: `$(function() {
            $('*').not('td > div.circle.marked').addClass('invis');
        })`. It also did not work

Comment: Its targeting anything with the class circle. Put all your HTML here and it would be easier to help you.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.circle.marked {visibility:visible; }
.circle{visibility:hidden;}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="white">
        <table class="circleDataBack">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="circle">A</div>
                    <div class="circle">B</div>
                    <div class="circle marked">C</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.circle:not(.marked){ visibility: hidden; }
```

```html
<div class="white">
        <table class="circleDataBack">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="circle">A</div>
                    <div class="circle">B</div>
                    <div class="circle marked">C</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried your css code, it made invisible only the elements inside the circle class, other elements outside the `marked` class stay visible

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/0emw0kL6/
here is simple css property that will help you.

```
<!-- CSS STARTS-->
.circle{
  display:none;
}
.marked{
  display:block;
}
<!-- CSS STARTS-->
<!-- HTML STARTS-->
<body>
    <div class="white">
        <table class="circleDataBack">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="circle">A</div>
                    <div class="circle">B</div>
                    <div class="circle marked">C</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
<!-- HTML ENDS-->
```